# CMake can't find OpenCVConfig.cmake

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, cmake

I'm trying to make OpenCV work with CMake in Clion on Windows 10 (64bit). I've already set `OPENCV_DIR` to the OpenCV build folder that contains `OpenCVConfig.cmake`, but cmake keeps nagging it cannot find the file.

```
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV" with any of the following names:
  OpenCVConfig.cmake   opencv-config.cmake
```

Here's my CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(MyProject)

set(OpenCV_DIR "D:/opencv/build/")

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED core imgproc)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(MyProject main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(MyProject ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

And here's the content of the `D:/opencv/build/` folder:

[image]

What can be the problem here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am unsure, but shouldn't this be a *Windows* path: `"D:\\opencv\\build"`?

Comment: On Windows the slash `\ ` can be replaced with `/` to avoid string escaping. But I did also try `\\\` but it didn't work either :(

Comment: Hmm, this could be a confusion between *cache* and *non-cache* variables: Description for [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/find_package.html) tells that it sets **cache entry** `<package>_DIR`, so it could expect pre-existed value also being cached. Try to set *cached* variable instead of normal one: via `-D` option for command line, via CMake cache editing or with `set(.. CACHE)`. Alternatively, you may pass given hint as `PATH` option for `find_package` call.

Comment: Okay, so I followed [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28365597/cmake-force-find-package-to-update-cache-variables) to clear the cache before `find_package`, but it didn't work either. Btw, I think it doesn't matter (yet) since cmake haven't successfully found opencv yet before it can cache.

Comment: No needs in clearing cache, you need to **setup it**. Whether you do this after (unsuccessfull) `cmake` call or not is unrelated.

Comment: I'd pass the path to OpenCV vie the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39126731/2799037

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem, totally unexpected for a CMake newcomer like me.

It turns out I installed CMake as part of Cygwin, and thus filesystem paths take the form of `/cygdrive/d/opencv/build/` instead. That works without a problem.

So if you're on Windows, please note the different file path style in case CMake is provided by Cygwin.